# Show that $\sup_{x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathscr{X}}|\mathscr{F}(x_1, \dots, x_n)|=S(\mathscr{A}, n)$

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

Show that $$\sup_{x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathscr{X}}|\mathscr{F}(x_1, \dots, x_n)|=S(\mathscr{A}, n)$$
where $S(\mathscr{A}, n)$ denotes the n-th shattering number of the class
$$\mathscr{A}=\{A_f: f \in \mathscr{F}\}$$
where 
$$A_f = \{x \in \mathscr{X}: f(x) = 1\}$$

I don't quite understand how to approach this problem. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does $|\mathscr{F}(x_1,\dots, x_n)|$ stand for?

Comment: Having thought a little - I'm guessing $\mathscr{F}(x)$ is the set $\{(f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n) ), f \in \mathscr{F}\},$ and the $f$ are $\{0,1\}$-valued. In addition, you define the shattering number in the set-inclusion sense. If this is the case, argue pointwise - fix a set of inputs $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, and consider the map $\varphi: \mathscr{A}(X) \to \mathscr{F}(X), (A_f \cap X) \mapsto (f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n) ).$ Argue that this is a bijection (this is almost trivial), to get that for any $X$, $\mathscr{A}(X)$ and $\mathscr{F}(X)$ are of equal size. The conclusion then follows.